# cant get the values of child in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<span class="employeesList">
    <div class="hrEmployees"><span class="employeesSection">all categories  <span class="pointerDown">&nbsp;</span></span></div>
</span>
```

I am doing this to get the inner html of `employeesSection`

```
$('.employeesList').children(':first-child').next().html();
```

but thats not working out... any idea what I may be doing worng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`children(':first-child')` selects the div, and `next()` attempts to select its next sibling, which doesn't exist.

Try this instead:

```
$('.employeesList').children(':first-child').children('span').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `find` method here.

```
$('.employeesList').children(':first-child').find('.employeesSection')html();
```

`next` is used for sibling elements and the first child has no siblings  in this case

You can simply use this selector

```
$('.employeesList').find('.hrEmployees > .employeesSection')html();
```